# Error inserting data derived from Inner Join query

Tags: mysql, database, join, inner-join

I'm attempting to query a MySQL database to `INSERT` the derived output from an `INNER JOIN` into a blank third table. Structure goes as follows:

Table A: `firstName` VARCHAR(100), `lastName` VARCHAR(100)
Table B: `firstName` VARCHAR(100), `lastName` VARCHAR(100), `extension` VARCHAR(5)
Table C: `firstName` VARCHAR(100), `lastName` VARCHAR(100), `extension` VARCHAR(5)

Table A has the list of names I need to match the extensions in Table B. Table B has names and extensions, but I only need a certain subset of these names and extensions (those which match the first and last names in Table A).

I'm able to run the following query successfully; however, I'm not entirely sure if I trust the output of 42 rows:

```
SELECT ta.extension, da.firstName, da.lastName
FROM <tableB> AS ta
INNER JOIN <tableA> AS da
ON (ta.firstName=da.firstName)
INNER JOIN <tableA> AS dl
ON (ta.lastName=dl.lastName)
ORDER BY da.firstName;
```

This query works, but again, I can't be positive that it's providing me with 100% accurate results (I'm worried a few may be missing, more than anything).

The following query does NOT work:

```
INSERT INTO <tableC>
SELECT ta.extension, da.firstName, da.lastName
FROM <tableB> AS ta
INNER JOIN <tableA> AS da
ON (ta.firstName=da.firstName)
INNER JOIN <tableA> AS dl
ON (ta.lastName=dl.lastName)
ORDER BY da.firstName;
```

The second query returns the following error:

`ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'extension' at row 88`

I've looked this up and I found that there's a hard max for the amount of rows a table can contain with long data-types - that's why I modified my table columns to be `VARCHAR(100)`, down from `VARCHAR(255)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining to `Table A` twice. You should only do it once so you can get the filtered records from `Table B` which have corresponding records from `Table A`

```
SELECT ta.extension, da.firstName, da.lastName
    FROM <tableB> AS ta
    INNER JOIN <tableA> AS da ON ta.firstName = da.firstName AND ta.lastName = da.lastName
    ORDER BY da.firstName;
```

For the `ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'extension' at row 88` error, yes, it has something to do with the `length` of the value. Please show us the original schema of your tables before you modified them.

**UPDATE 1**

If the table schema in your question is in correct order, the records from the `SELECT` statement will be inserted in to that table with respect to the column's order. The error is caused by inserting the `LastName` to the `Extension` column.

From the table schema, you have `firstName`, `lastName`, and `extension`
Then in the `SELECT` statement, we should follow the same order:

```
INSERT INTO <tableC>
SELECT da.firstName, da.lastName, ta.extension
        FROM ...
```

Another option is to specify the column names in the `INSERT INTO` statement

```
INSERT INTO <tableC> (Extension, FirstName, LastName)
SELECT ta.extension, da.firstName, da.lastName
        FROM ...
```

Comment: I thought that I had to basically `INNER JOIN` twice in order to achieve the same functionality as `AND`, based on my research. I should've just tried it that way from the beginning - I will now.

My original table schemas were the exact same, except in each table, the `firstName` and `lastName` columns each had datatype `VARCHAR(255)`. `extension` has always been datatype `VARCHAR(5)` because the extensions generally aren't longer than 4 numbers in length. I made it VARCHAR in case an extension had a wild character instead of an integer.

Comment: I think the problems lies in the `ORDER` of your `SELECT` statement. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You were right about the order of values I was attempting to `SELECT`. Once I tried this, the correct 31 rows were output.<br><br>However, I'm still getting the error: "Data too long for column 'extension' at row 88. `firstName` and `lastName` are both VARCHAR(100) in all three tables, and in the two that have the `extension` column, this datatype is `VARCHAR(5)` in each table.<br><br>Neither format of `INSERT INTO` works - I get the same error as described above for either suggestion.

Comment: I guess it is better if you will ask a separate question for that, don't forget to provide the schema of your tables with sample records in them.